# Moderncvstyle{classic} + linkedin logo won't stay where it is supposed to

Tags: moderncv, logos

Using `moderncv`, I can't get my linkedin-logo to stay under my contact-info, where I want it.
I've tried packages such as marvosym, awesome and fontawesome. Fontawesome did put the linkedin logo into my CV, but in a completely wrong placement (top left corner).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 


\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}


\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} 


\name{fornavn mellemnavn}{efternavn}
%\address{}{Aalborg}
\phone{+45 12345678}  
\email{aau.dk}  
\faLinkedin{navn}

\begin{document} 




\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{aau logo.png}
\end{minipage}


\recipient{Ansøgning vedrørende studiejob}{}
\opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
\closing{Med venlig hilsen,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
  
\makelettertitle

\justifying

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% write %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\vspace{0.5cm}

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That code generates multiple errors. Pay attention to them `\faLinkedin` is the code for directly inserting the icon, not a command for setting the value of other commands used later on like `\phone` and `\email`: you can't insert things like that in the preamble. Could you specify a bit more about what you want? Do you want it in the same font/color/style as the phone and email lines, right justified underneath them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moderncv` class has the command `\extrainfo` for such links, as described in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/manual/moderncv_userguide.pdf) on page 2.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} 

\name{fornavn mellemnavn}{efternavn}
%\address{}{Aalborg}
\phone{+45 12345678}  
\email{aau.dk}  
\extrainfo{\faLinkedin{\ navn}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{aau logo.png}
\end{minipage}


\recipient{Ansøgning vedrørende studiejob}{}
\opening{\vspace*{-2em}}
\closing{Med venlig hilsen,}{\vspace*{-2em}}
  
\makelettertitle

\justifying

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% write %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\vspace{0.5cm}

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Note that I also added a space (using `\` ) to separate the logo from the text.

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!